Gemini API: cURL command successfully calls API, but my program does not
I am trying to experiment with the Gemini API using Python in VSCode. Unfortunately, when running the boilerplate code in the IDE, I run into a KeyError. Below is the error I get.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "REDACTED", line 7, in <module>
    genai.configure(api_key=os.environ[my_API_key])
                            ~~~~~~~~~~^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen os>", line 685, in __getitem__
KeyError: 'REDACTED'

Note that "my_API_key" is a variable that I set to my personal API key within the program, and "REDACTED" in the last line of the error is my API key.
In accordance with the recommendations outlined in Google AI Studio, I created an API key, and tested the API by running the cURL command provided on the page:
curl \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"contents":[{"parts":[{"text":"Explain how AI works"}]}]}' \
  -X POST 'https://generativelanguage.googleapis.com/v1beta/models/gemini-1.5-flash-latest:generateContent?key=YOUR_API_KEY'

When replacing "YOUR_API_KEY" with the personal API key I created, I was able to successfully receive the response to the given prompt in my Terminal.
However, in VSCode, this is not the case. Below is the boilerplate code that I copied from Google and pasted in the IDE.
import pathlib
import textwrap
import google.generativeai as genai
import os

my_API_key = 'REDACTED'
genai.configure(api_key=os.environ[my_API_key])

model = genai.GenerativeModel(name='gemini-pro')
response = model.generate_content('Prove the Pythagorean theorem')

print(response.text)

When running this program, I receive the error message provided above. I ran this code both in VSCode and a Jupyter notebook, and received the same error message. I would appreciate any advice directing me in the correct direction to resolving this basic issue, or any fixes that worked for similar issues in the past. Thank you!

I understand you do not want your personal API key showing in your application code, but if you wrote your API key straight into genai.configure(api_key = your_api_key), it should work.

@IfeanyiIdiaye Unfortunately, I run into the same error even when I remove the my_API_key variable and simply paste my API key into genai.configure(api_key = os.environ[API_KEY]).

I hope you also have Python properly installed on your computer. Try running it in a virtual environment or in Google Colab with T4 NVIDIA GPU enabled in runtime.

@IfeanyiIdiaye Yes, Python is properly installed, in addition to all of the necessary modules.

The error ⚠️  is that you are trying to get a value from your environment variables that does not exist. Try print(os.environ), can you see your keys?

@PraysonW.Daniel The key was not in os.environ, that's why! Thank you. Also, thank you ifeanyildiaye — when I pasted in the api key to genai.configure and removed "name=" from genai.GenerativeModel, it worked!

I am happy for you!

I was having the same issues and, after much frustration and reverse engineering, I found out that the python package is faulty and does not work (at least not always). So in the end I just used the request package and wrapped the cURL calls into functions, and it worked perfectly.

Use 'GOOGLE_API_KEY'
import google.generativeai as genai

GOOGLE_API_KEY=('MY_API_KEY')
genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

model = genai.GenerativeModel('gemini-1.5-flash')
response = model.generate_content("The opposite of hot is")
print(response.text)

